# How to search word in file that include dollar sign ($) using awk

Tags: linux, awk

I want to catch the lines that include that to following pattern:
word1, word2, ^word3$, word4

I want to check if the third word in the line is equal to word3, the ^ and $ signs always will be in the third column using awk.
something like this:

```
less file.txt | awk '{if ($3=="^word3$") {print $0}}'
```

and this will print the line, i just cant grab the word with the ^ and $ signs.

How can i do it?
(I must use awk because the original command is more complicated and i can't use grep)

Thanks!

Comment: When you have funny characters in your regex, it is always safe to just inclose them in square brackets: `[^]word3[$]`

Comment: is your problem to extract `"word3"` from the literal string `"^word3$"`?

Answer (score 0):

**Edited:** the words of the input are separated by a space and a comma. So the `awk` command needs the `-F ", "` option.

If you use the operator `==`, `awk` will perform an exact match. If you want to use a regex, you will have to use the `~` operator. So you have two solutions:

Exact match:

```
awk -F ", " '($3 == "word3") {print}' file.txt
```

Regex:

```
awk -F ", " '($3 ~ "^word3$") {print}' file.txt
```

Since `{print}` is the instruction executed by default, you can even drop that part and only issue:

```
awk -F ", " '($3 ~ "^word3$")' file.txt
```

But if I read your question again and again, I start thinking you want to extract `^word3$` from your text. In that case, what you need is:

```
awk -F ", " '($3 == "^word3$")' file.txt
```

(without square brackets in this case, as suggested somewhere).

An equivalent solution without redefining the field separator is to put the comma inside of the string you are trying to match:

```
awk '($3 == "^word3$,")' file.txt
```

Comment: @ניב אדלשטיין : I suggest you next time to include a sample of your input in your posts in order to avoid guesses from the persons trying to help you.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I am sorry that i wasn't so clear, my problem isn't with the "," separator,  the problem is with the ^ and $ signs, i can catch them in the awk statement, they are special sign. when i try to do this: ($3 == "^word3$") nothing happened